# VBA – Find object in array with specific property

Tags: arrays, vba, search, user-defined-types

Let's say I have an object called `Card` which has several properties like `color`, `number`, `suit`, etc. Then I store a bunch of `Card`s in an array called `deck`. Is there a way to search the `deck` for a `Card` with a specific property or set of properties?

Thanks!

Theoretical code for `Card`:

```
Public color As String
Public suit As String
Public number As Integer
```

Comment: Yes. Post your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @coinbird I posted the code for `Card` above. I am looking for a function like `deck.findFirstElementThatQualifies(.number = 7)` or something like that, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching through data is a massive part of programming. There are countless ways to search depending on your needs. To do a basic linear search you could make a loop to the length of the array, and check each array element to see if it meets your criteria.

Since you haven't tried anything yet, or told us what you want to do with the data you find (or don't find) I'll give you some pseudo code to start you off:

```
for(counter integer that increments until it is equal to the length of the array)
{
    if(array at position[counter] == the color/suit/number your looking for)
    {
        //do whatever
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

You could make this into a function that takes input, and returns data, so you could call it with whatever data you want to find.

If this doesn't make sense to you, you will need to start by researching loops.

Comment: Thanks. This should work, but I imagine it will take a while if I am doing it many times.

Comment: @AriLevisohn You're right, it absolutely will take a long time. There are extremely complex searching and sorting algorithms that would help you do this faster, but you need to learn to use basic searches before the complex ones will make sense. You also need specific goals of your search. If you can perfectly define what you want your program to find, and what to do with that data, you can make your searches faster.